# TCP Sockets Server Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I currently have a Windows Application that uses TCP Sockets to connect users and send/receive data. The application crashes when a new user tries to connect while several other users (never the same amount of users) are already connected and receiving data. My application needs to receive data from one person and send it out to many users. The application receives data couple times a second.

The last thing my code does before error error is trying to add a new client to the list.  It seems like when trying to connect a new user it is interfering with the data attempting to be sent.

```
private static void EndAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Listener_Socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    ClientsList.Add(Listener_Socket.EndAccept(ar));
    Listener_Socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(EndAccept), Listener_Socket);
    ...
    AsyncCallback receiveData = new AsyncCallback(MyServer.OnReceivedData);
}
```

Event Viewer Error:

> Application: xxxxxxxxxxxx.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException Stack: at
>   System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple.MoveNext() at
>   MyServer.OnRecievedData(System.IAsyncResult)
>   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode,
>   CleanupCode, System.Object) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at
>   System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32,
>   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*) at
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32,
>   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)

OnRecievedData:

```
private static void OnRecievedData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        SocketClient client = (SocketClient)ar.AsyncState;
        byte[] aryRet = client.GetRecievedData(ar);

        if (aryRet.Length < 1)
        {
            client.ReadOnlySocket.Close();
            ClientsList.Remove(client);
            return;
        }
        foreach (SocketClient clientSend in ClientsList)
        {
            if (client != clientSend)
                try
                {
                    clientSend.ReadOnlySocket.NoDelay = true;
                    clientSend.ReadOnlySocket.Send(aryRet);
                }
                catch
                {
                    clientSend.ReadOnlySocket.Close();
                    ClientsList.Remove(client);
                    return;
                }
        }
        client.SetupRecieveCallback();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a client connects, `EndAccept` will usually be invoked on another thread than the thread `OnRecievedData` is running on. If `EndAccept` happens in the middle of the foreach, the enumerator is no longer valid (the collection has changed).

You should use some kind of synchronization mechanism like `lock` to prevent this from happening.

And I even missed what Suhas mentions; the collection is modified from within the same thread, too.

Comment: I'be put a lock around my foreach but the program still crashes with the same error.

Comment: You can only protect an object from being changed if all access to the object uses the same lock. You could create a `readonly object _myClientListLock = new object()` and lock on that anytime you access your list.

Comment: If clients are connected to the server to listen to the ports and the sending gets behind, is this because of the server side or client side ?

Comment: would `lock(ClientList.SyncRoot)` be just as sufficient or not?

Answer (score 1):

A possibility - You should not modify a list when you are iterating that list. In your example above you are removing item from `ClientsList` inside the `foreach` loop on `ClientsList`

Comment: Doesn't `AsyncCallback recieveData = new AsyncCallback(MyServer.OnRecievedData);` and `Listener_Socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(EndAccept), Listener_Socket);` run on different threads?

Comment: I'm referring to the code in `try...catch` block in `OnReceiveData`'s `foreach` block